# Get Location based on the area User Selects

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to implement Google Maps in an Android App. I have configured to get current Location and get the details like locality, Street and other details.

Now, there is another scenario where user can select area upfront. In this case, i would like to read the area(co-ordinates) which he has selected and display the area location on google map.

Here is my code:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Log.d(TAG, "OnMapReady");
    mMap = googleMap;


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
            Log.d("Camera position change" + "", cameraPosition + "");

            mCenterLatLong = cameraPosition.target;
            mMap.clear();
            try {
                Location mLocation = new Location("");
                mLocation.setLatitude(mCenterLatLong.latitude);
                mLocation.setLongitude(mCenterLatLong.longitude);
                startIntentService(mLocation);
                mLocationMarkerText.setText("Lat : " + mCenterLatLong.latitude + "," + "Long : " + mCenterLatLong.longitude);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
}
```

Can anyone guide me to achieve this one?

Comment: Is your question about [geoencoding](https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html)? There are many examples for [that](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=en).

Comment: Actually, i am getting required information for current location. Now, I want to disable current location and give coordinates. Based on that, i would like to show the map. How can i achieve this?\